# script stop working when I load it inside a div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I got this function in my html for a simply validation...

```
<script>
  function pwdcheck(dataPwd) {
  var parametros = {
    "dataPwd" : dataPwd
  };
  $.ajax({
    data: parametros,
    url: 'check.php',
    type: 'post',
    beforeSend: function () {
      $("#infomsg").html("checking, please wait...");
    },
    success: function (response) {
      $("#infomsg").html(response);
    }
  });
}
```

and this check.php

```
<?php
  $clave = 'cocacola';
  if(trim($_POST['dataPwd'])==$clave) {
    // redirect to some page
  }else{
    echo "Incorrect Password!";
  }
?>
```

and the problem is that when I use it directly from this first html that I showed you... all works perfect, but when I load this html inside a div (#section), its stop working displaying the "checking, please wait..." message.

Someone could please help me?! Thanks!

Comment: How are you calling the `pwdcheck` function?

Comment: Can you add the HTML in question?

Comment: I'm calling the function from the html that I loaded into the div, with this button:
<button class="btn btn-default" href="javascript:;" onclick="pwdcheck($('#defaultForm-pass').val());return true;"
I dont upload the other page yet because I m working with MDBootstrap and its a lot of code, I will try to clean it and then I will share it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I solved the problem! Thanks to all! you gave me ideas to try some things step by step...
The problem was that the php file was in another directory... and ajax seems to arrive in one way but php cant find a way to return I think... php echo dont cross directories :P

What I tried was this.

I had main.html who loads in his #section validate.html who was the one who has the ajax inside to communicate with check.php, validate.html and check.php were in another directory.
The solution was only moving the check.php to the same directory than main.html, and it worked even keeping validate.html in the other directory... weird no?! at least for me that I dont know so much :P

Thanks again to all, Leandro.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function pwdcheck(dataPwd) {
    var parametros = {
        "dataPwd" : dataPwd
    };
    $.ajax({
        data: parametros,
        url: 'check.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType:'html',
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#infomsg").html("checking, please wait...");
        },
        success: function (response) {
            $("#infomsg").html(response);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: You  must need to use dataType:'html'